# How do I make a new submodule in a remote Git repo?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, remote-repository

I'm working on an open source project, "Project", which has two submodules, "Submodule1" and "Submodule2", with URLs "github.com/Project/Submodule1" and "github.com/Project/Submodule2".

I want to create a new submodule, "Submodule3". I've created it on my local machine, but I don't know how to get it into the remote repo on Github.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Clarification:**

`Submodule3` will be a copy of `Submodule2`, that I will edit. `Submodule2` is the template that I want to base `Submodule3` on. So what I want to do is clone `Submodule2` inside `Project` on my local machine, make changes to it, then push it to the remote repo as `Submodule3`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is documentation page that is of your interest. There you can read that

> To add a new submodule you use the `git submodule add` command with the
>   absolute or relative URL of the project you would like to start
>   tracking. In this example, we’ll add a library called “DbConnector”.
>
> ```
> $ git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
> Cloning into 'DbConnector'...
> remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
> remote: Total 11 (delta 0), reused 11 (delta 0)
> Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
> ```

Comment: Hi Enrico. I'm on github.com/Project, and if I click the 'create new repo' button, it creates a new repo NOT within Project. I assume that I should find a way to create it on Github inside the Project repo, and then when I push my from local machine, push to that new submodule, but I don't know how to create the new repo inside of Project. Do you know?

Comment: Speaking about the other two projects, are those two just two directories in the `Project` directory corresponding to the only GitHub repo you are mentioning? If so, you just need to commit and push everything up to the repo. If this is not case, please clarifiy your workflow (**in the question, not here in the comments**); if you simply get errors, please share them (**in the question, not here in the comments**).

Comment: I added clarification to the end of the question.